# stop marker animation in google maps with multiple markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have a map integrated on my web page with marker animation. I have multiple markers in the map. I want to achieve something like, when any of the marker is clicked then other marker's animation should stop which is currently running.

Currently i am able to stop animation of the same marker on the marker click. There must be some marker object i should get in the case of multiple markers.

So far i have done this.

latlngarray is an array with lattitude and longitude in object format.

```
var centerlatlng={center lat lng are here};
var zoomlevel=zoomlevel is here;
function initMap(){
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
    center: centerlatlng,
    zoom: zoomlevel
});

if(latlngarray.length > 0){
    for(i=0; i < latlngarray.length; i++){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlngarray[i],
            map: map
        });

        marker.addListener('click', function(){
            toggleBounce(this);
            map.setZoom(10);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        });
    }
}}

function toggleBounce(ele){
if(ele.getAnimation() !== null){
    ele.setAnimation(null);
}else{
    ele.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
}}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sandeeppujare/prqvfmbf/1/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an array with references to all the markers, iterate through that array cancelling the animation on all the markers, then set the animation on the clicked marker.

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    markers[i].setAnimation(null);
  }
  toggleBounce(this);
  map.setZoom(10);
  map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/qmboxs2u/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var centerlatlng = {
  lat: 37.4419,
  lng: -122.1419
};
var zoomlevel = 13;
var latlngarray = [{lat: 37.4418834, lng: -122.1430195}, // Palo Alto, CA, USA
  {lat: 37.4688273, lng: -122.1410751}, //East Palo Alto, CA, USA
  {lat: 37.424106, lng: -122.1660756}, // Stanford, CA, USA 
  {lat: 37.4529598, lng: -122.1817252} // Menlo Park, CA, USA 
];

function initMap() {
  var markers = [];
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: centerlatlng,
    zoom: zoomlevel
  });

  if (latlngarray.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < latlngarray.length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlngarray[i],
        map: map
      });
      markers.push(marker);

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          markers[i].setAnimation(null);
        }
        toggleBounce(this);
        map.setZoom(10);
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
      });
    }
  }
}

function toggleBounce(ele) {
  if (ele.getAnimation() !== null) {
    ele.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    ele.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```