# google maps marker stop

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

this is my google maps code 
ı want to google maps marker stop 
help me please !!!

```
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    // initialize marker

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        draggable: true,
        map: map


    });

    //marker.forEach(function (marker) {
    //    marker.setMap(null);
    //});
    //marker = [];
    // intercept map and marker movements
    window.google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
        marker.setPosition(map.getCenter());
        var latitude = map.getCenter().lat().toFixed(6);
        var longitude = map.getCenter().lng().toFixed(6);
        window.google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
        getLocationAdressName(latitude, longitude);
        marker.dragging.disable();

    });
```

Comment: Do you want it to stop being draggable?

Comment: [Plese check this question it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507427/stop-marker-animation-in-google-maps-with-multiple-markers)

Comment: yep ı want to stop being draggable

Comment: you want to drag the marker just once, then stop? or not draggable at all?

Answer (score 1):

As dev8080 answered, if you want your marker to be not draggable at all then you should go with his answer.

But if you want your marker stop being draggable after some event replace

this:

```
 marker.dragging.disable();
```

with this:

```
 marker.setDraggable(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the pointer with draggable:false. To set the marker's center, you need not enable it's draggable attribute.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    draggable: false,
    map: map
});
```